# Global variable empty in page load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I created a List as global variable in my page.

```
public static List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSalles = new List<LinkButton>();
```

And in a function called during `Page_Load`, I add some elements like this:

```
foreach (var childControl in allControlsLinkButton)
{
    if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalleActive" ||  childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalle")
    {
        allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Add(childControl);
    }
}
```

Just after that, when I do this:

```
foreach (LinkButton value in allControlsLinkButtonSalles)
{
    literal2.Text += " <br /> Text " + value.Text;
}
```

And there are definitely 3 elements that show up.
However when I try to do this:

```
literal2.Text += " First element " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.First().Text;
```

An error occurs. How come that is possible ?

Here is the message:

> Description : An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Check the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The sequence contains no elements.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Ligne 605 :        }
>   Ligne 606 :
>   Ligne 607 :        literal2.Text += " First " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.First().Text;
>   Ligne 608 :
>   Ligne 609 :        //allControlsLinkButtonSalles[0].CssClass = "linkButtonSalleActive";
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The sequence contains no elements.]
>       System.Linq.Enumerable.First (IEnumerable `1 source) +269
>      test2MasterPage.Page_init() in c:\Users....\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\test1\test2MasterPage.aspx.cs:607
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +9807957
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +92
>      System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +134
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +489

Here is the complete code:

```
public static List<DataTable> ListTable = new data().GetTable();
public static List<string> SallesList = new data().SallesListCreation(ListTable[0]);

//DataTable dt = new data().
public static int Load_Counter = 0;
List<Button> allControlsButton = new List<Button>();
public static List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSalles = new List<LinkButton>();

List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonAffichages = new List<LinkButton>();
List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSemaine = new List<LinkButton>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    literal2.Text += "<br /> counter : " + Load_Counter.ToString();
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    string sToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    string finDate = today.AddDays(+6).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    literaltest.Text = "Semaine du " + sToday + " au " + finDate;

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br /><br /> kyofu<br /><br />"));

    foreach (string sallesel in SallesList)
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CreateLinkButton(sallesel + "lkbtn", sallesel, "linkButtonSalle"));
    }

    Page_init();
}

protected void Page_init()
{
    List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButton = new List<LinkButton>();
    GetControlList<LinkButton>(Page.Controls, allControlsLinkButton);
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    string sToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    // the list of controllers is filled
    foreach (var childControl in allControlsLinkButton)
    {
        if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalleActive" ||  childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalle")
        {
            allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Add(childControl);
            literal2.Text += " allControlsLinkButtonSalles " + childControl.Text;
        }

        if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonAffichage" ||  childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonAffichageActive")
        {
            allControlsLinkButtonAffichages.Add(childControl);
        }
        if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSemaine" || childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSemaineActive")
        {
            allControlsLinkButtonSemaine.Add(childControl);
            SemaineSync(childControl);
        }
    }
    literal2.Text += " taille " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Count();
    //literal2.Text += " Text " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles[1].Text;

    foreach (LinkButton value in allControlsLinkButtonSalles)
    {
        literal2.Text += " <br /> Text " + value.Text;
    }

    literal2.Text += " First " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.First().Text;
    ListFilmsBySalle(SallesList[0]);
}

private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T> resultCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
        if (control is T) // This is cleaner
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);

        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the error show stack trace.

Comment: It's important to know *where* you try to access the list.

Comment: Please see the updated message, I try to access it right after adding elements.

Comment: I don't understand French.

Comment: To sum up it means there is no element in the sequence.

Comment: It's not totally clear what happens but the remedy will be: do not use `static` data in a web app.

Comment: even if I remove `static` it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? To retrieve the first element on a list, if it's .NET 3.5 or above, you can use LINQ (`.First()`), otherwise, the index (like an array) `mylist[0]`.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 I think.

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong in your code. Maybe if you post it again but as a whole (the `PageLoad` block). And I'm assuming you're using `WebForms` and not `MVC`, right?

Comment: I am not fluent in French but that error *appears* to be along the lines of `the sequence contains no elements`. Either your list is being emptied *before* you access it or nothing is actually being added to start with.

Comment: I added the complete Code. @James : I am adding elements jsut before the call.

Comment: @Exia0890 like I said have you actually debugged this and checked that the items are being added? There is a good possibility your `allControlsLinkButton` is empty or none of the conditions match so nothing get's added to the `allControlLinkButtonSalles` list.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by debug, but just before the call of First(), I am doing a foreach, and it does print me the elements that should be there.

Comment: Its kinda alien exception for me.. if possible paste its eng version

Comment: I've translated it to english. The edit should be accepted in a moment...

Comment: Thanks for the translation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the static key word properly.
Static variable, is belong to the class itself and don't belong to the current instanace.

Try to use:

```
   public List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSalles
   {
       get
       {
           if(Session["allControlsLinkButtonSalles"] == null)
               Session["allControlsLinkButtonSalles"] = new List<LinkButton>();
           return (List<LinkButton>) Session["allControlsLinkButtonSalles"];

       }
       set
       {
           Session["allControlsLinkButtonSalles"] = value;
       }
   }
```

Another isue to take look for is that actually something enter to the list, try to debug it.

Comment: It tells me that `session` doesn't exist.

Comment: That should be `Session` with a capital `S`.

Comment: There is an error with `if(Session["allControlsLinkButtonSalles"])` telling me an object type can't be converted in bool.

Comment: Try to do it on page load, the control initalize in page innit, it probably stil null.

Comment: Well, one fix is that I passed `allControlsLinkButtonSalles` as parameter to Page_init(). So I suppose your solution will work too ( can't test it for now) . But it does not really tell me why I can't use it as a global variable. In the function relative to the Link Buttons, `allControlsLinkButtonSalles` does work, but only for Page_Init() it does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a Static Class and Create some Attributes and Set your Values to those     

Attributes their Whenever you Want you can take it from their if Data has any change 

Again set those attributes so that you will get your data from the Class

Public static class Helper
     {
        public string SOMEPROPERTY
          {
             get;
             set;
          }
              .
              .
              .

        public List<LinkButton> SOMEPROPERTY
          {
             get;
             set;
          }


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error as you at first, realised I had no controls in the *List* you are looking at because I had no *LinkButton* s with either of the classes that were being searched for with regard to the *allControlsLinkButtonSalles* list.

I added the CssClass of ""linkButtonSalleActive"" on all of the *LinkButton* s on my page and I got no debug error.

Add in a check that the list is actually empty for the times where there are no *Salle* specific links, and you shouldn't have any issues.

Here is the sample code I worked with:

Default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="literal2" /> <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="literaltest" /> <br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonSalleActive" text="1"/>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonSalleActive" text="2"/>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonSalleActive" text="3"/>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonSalleActive" text="4"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs (modified version of you complete code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //DataTable dt = new data().
        public static int Load_Counter = 0;
        List<Button> allControlsButton = new List<Button>();
        public static List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSalles = new List<LinkButton>();

        List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonAffichages = new List<LinkButton>();
        List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButtonSemaine = new List<LinkButton>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            literal2.Text += "<br /> counter : " + Load_Counter.ToString();
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string sToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string finDate = today.AddDays(+6).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            literaltest.Text = "Semaine du " + sToday + " au " + finDate;

            //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br /><br /> kyofu<br /><br />"));

            //foreach (string sallesel in SallesList)
            //{
            //    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CreateLinkButton(sallesel + "lkbtn", sallesel, "linkButtonSalle"));
            //}

            Page_init();
        }

        protected void Page_init()
        {
            List<LinkButton> allControlsLinkButton = new List<LinkButton>();
            GetControlList<LinkButton>(Page.Controls, allControlsLinkButton);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string sToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            // the list of controllers is filled
            foreach (var childControl in allControlsLinkButton)
            {
                if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalleActive" || childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalle")
                {
                    allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Add(childControl);
                    literal2.Text += " allControlsLinkButtonSalles " + childControl.Text;
                }

                if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonAffichage" || childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonAffichageActive")
                {
                    allControlsLinkButtonAffichages.Add(childControl);
                }
                if (childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSemaine" || childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSemaineActive")
                {
                    allControlsLinkButtonSemaine.Add(childControl);
                    //SemaineSync(childControl);
                }
            }
            literal2.Text += " taille " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Count();
            //literal2.Text += " Text " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles[1].Text;

            foreach (LinkButton value in allControlsLinkButtonSalles)
            {
                literal2.Text += " <br /> Text " + value.Text;
            }

            /*
             * CHANGES HERE
             */

            literal2.Text += allControlsLinkButtonSalles.Count > 0 ?
                " First " + allControlsLinkButtonSalles.First().Text :
                String.Empty;
            //ListFilmsBySalle(SallesList[0]);
        }

        private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T> resultCollection)
        where T : Control
        {
            foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
            {
                //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
                if (control is T) // This is cleaner
                    resultCollection.Add((T)control);

                if (control.HasControls())
                    GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't really add Linkbutton manually, since I don't know beforehand how many there will be.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code value to the list  `allControlsLinkButtonSalles` is added only if `childControl.CssClass == "linkButtonSalleActive"`,

I am sure there in no value being added, check what you are getting for `literal2.Text` at:-
`literal2.Text += " taille "+ allControlsLinkButtonSalles .Count();`

Having said that you should not be using static variables or properties on page unless you have a valid reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, unfortunatly I can't test anymore, I completly changed the code. As suggested I am not using static variables anymore. But I do remember doing `FirstOrDefault` and it did no work either.